# React native how do I Implement this mockup ? React native crop from photo

Tags: reactjs, react-native, crop

[image: ph]

Hi , I have a question, how to implement this mockup ? I it's like barcode scanner, but all I need is make sure the user centered id card and the system will automaticly crop that image, Is there has a package for this project ? thank you

Comment: Have you find the solution for this?

Comment: Have you find the solution for this..